# Allow users to delete their own comments via the front end

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have been trying to follow this tutorial - [How to provide a delete button for django built in comments framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771852/how-to-provide-a-delete-button-for-django-built-in-comments-framework). Unfortunately it is an old tutorial and some of the code is now out of date.

In it he uses the code `from django.contrib.comments.view.moderate import perform_delete`.

I then got an error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.comments'`.

I did `pip install django-contrib-comments`.

And I tried the following - `from django_comments.view.moderate import perform_delete`.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? 
        '

Comment: I've think you may need to change `django_comments.view.moderate` to `django_comments.views.moderation`. Answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [django-contrib-comments](https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/porting.html) documentation suggests the following-

Change the following-

```
from django.contrib.comments.view.moderate import perform_delete
```

To-

```
from django_comments.views.moderation import perform_delete
```

Make sure that you use `views.moderation` instead of `view.moderate`, and also in the settings.py file, you've added `'django_comments'` as INSTALLED_APPS.